# Best method to retrieve Active Directory list using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I am fairly new to ASP.NET programming. I am designing a web project which will maintain employees information, such as the approval schema, staff inventories, claims, etc. The database will record the employee ID as the key. Currently there is no local table storing the mapping of the employee ID and employee name. These information will be retrieved from the Active Directory.

The new system will allow user to do employee lookup e.g. based on name or ID and generate report e.g. list of employee claims of the month. The lookup can be achieved by directly accessing the AD but I don't think it's a good method for generating list of employees/reports. Hence, I'm planning to download the AD list to local database.

My questions are:
1. Is downloading AD list to local database the right method for this situation? Is there any other alternatives to achieve this?
2. Shall I go with downloading the AD list, how to update it on regular basis? I can only think of clearing the table and reimport the whole list again.

Any advises will be much welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/ I've used it before with great success

Answer (score 0):

> "The new system will allow user to do employee lookup e.g. based on name or ID and generate report e.g. list of employee claims of the month."

Sounds like you do not need all employees from AD at once. In that case I would not download the AD list at all, as that would put you in a situation where you have to deal with your database being out of date.
Just start with retrieving the data from AD on request and only think about optimizations if you encounter performance problems.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I agree with your points. For the employee look up, I can send request to AD during postback. However I'm stumbled on how to fetch employee name when generating a report e.g. on datagrid/RDL when the query only gives me the employee ID.